# Adding psql in shell script

Tags: shell, psql

I have this code `$(echo "psql -U postgres -d mydb -c "SELECT *  FROM table_name;"   " | ssh $REMOTE_IP)`

I need to run that query in the remote host, but i can't apply the query part in the echo

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect and you don't need to use pipe. Try this:

```
ssh "$REMOTE_IP" 'psql -U postgres -d mydb -c "SELECT *  FROM table_name;"'
```

Comment: @PedroOsório Glad to see it works. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.